# How to navigate to Activity from Sliding panel when the back button is pressed

Tags: android

I have an Fragment Activity with a sliding panel in it. I implemented the following so I exit the app when user presses the back button.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //this will close and exit the app
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//***Change Here***
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

However, I would like to stay in the same activity if the the user is on the sliding panel and wants to navigate back to the activity. Right now if the user presses the back button when the sliding panel is displayed, it closes the app. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using SlidingPanelLayout

```
mSlidingPanelLayout = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.label);
```

Then

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(mSlidingPanelLayout.isOpen())
    {
        mSlidingPanelLayout.closePane();
    }
    else 
    {
        //closeActivity();
    }
}
```

you can also use the PanelSlideListener

```
    mSlidingPanelLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelOpened(View panel) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelClosed(View panel) {

        }
    });
```